# How to display last check-in author name in eclipse starteam?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, starteam

I am using Star Team plugin in eclipse .

When viewing files in eclipse it appends all the information about the file version,last modified date to the file name but I was not able to append last checked-in author name to file.

Can any one help to identify this in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this specific plugin, but generally there are three places you check for this:

1. Preferences -> Team -> Star Team
2. In the `History` view, the view menu (upside down triangle on the right)
3. Also in the `History` view, check the meaning of all of the buttons on the toolbar there.

If none of those allows additional information, then it is likely that the Star Team provider needs to be extended. File a report with them.